# Issue On Passing index (or not) in $.each() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to keep track of checkbox state changes by following code but I am not sure if I have to pass any parameter (index) into anonymous function on  `$.each(, function(index))`

The reason that I am asking this is the code is functioning the same as the function is either taking or not the `index` as parameter but when I remove it I am getting this `object collection, function(Number, Object):Object callback` tooltip on the `$.each()`

[image]

```js
 $('input:checkbox[name=options]').on('change', function() {
            var val = '';
            $.each($('input:checkbox[name=options]:checked'), function(index) {
                val += $(this).val();
            });
            switch (val) {
                case 'a':
                    console.log(val);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    console.log(val);
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    console.log(val);
                    break;
                case 'ab':
                    console.log(val);
                    break;
                case 'ac':
                    console.log(val);
                    break;
                case 'abc':
                    console.log(val);
                    break;
                case 'bc':
                   console.log(val);
                    break;
               }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="a" />Red<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="b" />Yellow<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="c" />Orange<br/>
```

can you please let me know if this is correct or I should keep the index inside function even when I am nit using it?

Comment: if you're not using `index` inside the function, it doesn't matter whether you pass it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 versions of `each` one is `$.each` the other is `$.fn.each`

Use the `$.fn.each` syntax to iterate elements.

```
$(selector).each(function(){    
    //"this" is element
});
```

The other is typically used to iterate object literals and arrays.

As for which arguments you provide they are essentially optional although to use second you also need first

Reference :

[$.fn.each docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

[$.each docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, can you please let me know how I can replace the `$.each()` with `$.fn.each()` here?

Comment: i did...use your selector string in place of my `selector` placeholder...I couldn't copy from image.

Comment: SO it would be `$('input:checkbox[name=options]:checked').each(...` for your example